# Sharing result response API without state and outside then()

Tags: reactjs, response

```
var a = getdata()
a.then((result) => {
  console.log(result.data.data);
  this.setState({
    items: result.data.data
  });
})
console.log(result.data.data);
```

I want to share result.data.data to outside `then()`.
New to React and JS in general so I apologize for the simplistic nature of this question.

I'm attempting to store a single child's name from my API in React's state but I must be doing something incorrectly with the JSON as this state is never updated.

If someone could explain what I'm doing incorrect and the best way to accomplish this, I'd very much appreciate it. My code almost mirrors this but I can't seem to figure out whats wrong here.

Comment: It will be useful if you could share more code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access result variable outside your callback function. So you have to save it to the state variable and access it outside or anywhere else as `this.state.items`

Comment: i already do that's, but i want to callback result if can do that.